# Combined Mesh and Lightmap

Tags: unity, mesh, lightmap

I am using Unity 2017.

The left picture is the original state. Light map applied.

On the right is the state after all meshes are made into Combined Mesh.

Same lightmap settings as left.

As you can see, it is filled with dirty black dots.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combined your tiny mesh into a big one in code, such as following:

```
    Mesh newMesh = new Mesh();
    newMesh.name = "CombinedBig";
    newMesh.CombineMeshes(combineInstances, false, false);
    Unwrapping.GenerateSecondaryUVSet(newMesh);  // This line is necessary!!
    meshFilterCombine.sharedMesh = newMesh;
```

You need generate the secondary UVs set for the big mesh.